# How to place DisplayName into Variable

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, c#-2.0

I'm trying to do something, that may be extremely simple so please bear with me, I just want to get 'DisplayName' from an XML file into a string in my C# code. here's what I have:

#### THIS IS C#2.0 in VS2005

XML:

```
<MonitorScope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" id="System" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd">
    <PersonalSafety>    
<MonitorResponseRecord Enabled="false" DisplayName="ValveFailureAtCentralPosition">
<ExpressionMonitor>
<postAlarm>
<AlarmName>Valve_Position_Fault</AlarmName>
<Parameter1> Sensor Position = {X}</Parameter1>
<Parameter2> Sensor Position = {X}</Parameter2>
<Parameter3> Sensor Position = {X}</Parameter3>
</postAlarm>
</ExpressionMonitor>
</MonitorResponseRecord>
<MonitorResponseRecord ...  ... ...>
... ...
... ... and so on about 1600 times.
```

In my C# code I've attempted the following but to No Avail:
C#:

```
public class AlarmRecord
{
    /// <remarks/>
    public string PmAlarm;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Parameter1;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Parameter2;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Parameter3;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string DisplayName;
}

    protected void OnPostAlarm(PostAlarm postAlarm)
    {
        try 
        {
            AlarmRecord alarmRecord = new AlarmRecord(); 
            alarmRecord.PmAlarm    = postAlarm.AlarmName;
            alarmRecord.Parameter1 = postAlarm.Parameter1;
            alarmRecord.Parameter2 = postAlarm.Parameter2;
            alarmRecord.Parameter3 = postAlarm.Parameter3;
            
            string fileName = "UMSM.009.8Root.xml";
            string fullPath;
            fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(fileName);

            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(fullPath));
            System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument docNav = new System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument(reader);

            System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator Q = docNav.CreateNavigator();
            System.Xml.XPath.XPathExpression EXE = Q.Compile("MonitorResponseRecord/@DisplayName");
            alarmRecord.DisplayName = Convert.ToString(Q.Evaluate(EXE));
             alarms.Enqueue( alarmRecord ); 
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Write(e);
            OnUnknownResponse(postAlarm);
        }
    }
```

basically my current issue is that durring Debug the issue that I'm noticing is in the line where 'reader' is initialized... the program usually throws an exception here

Comment: take a look at LINQ to XML http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx

Comment: I cannot do LINQ, I should clarify this is C#2.0 Visual studio 2005. I'll add this info to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an XmlReader:

```
    protected void OnPostAlarm(PostAlarm postAlarm) 
    {
       AlarmRecord record = null;
       List<AlarmRecord> recordList = new List<AlarmRecord>();

        using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("Xml/bin/UMSM.009.8Root.xml"))
        {

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    switch (reader.Name)
                    {
                        case "MonitorResponseRecord":
                            record = new AlarmRecord();
                            recordList.Add(record);
                            reader.MoveToAttribute("DisplayName");
                            record.DisplayName = reader.Value;
                            break;

                        case "AlarmName":
                            record.PmAlarm = reader.ReadString();
                            break;

                        case "Parameter1":
                            record.Parameter1 = reader.ReadString();
                            break;

                        case "Parameter2":
                            record.Parameter2 = reader.ReadString();
                            break;

                        case "Parameter3":
                            record.Parameter3 = reader.ReadString();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("\Xml\bin\UMSM.009.8Root.xml")   just crashes the program

Comment: I edited the code example. You have to delete the slash in front of "Xml/...". The path is relative to your execution file.

Comment: relative to exacutable? well all the exacutables for this program are stored in C:\Proj\Run\bin\   while all Xml files are in the above C:\Proj\Xml\bin\   so would I put proj\Xml\bin\UMSM....?

Comment: Two options: 1.) use absolute path. or 2.) navigate relative from your executable, in your case "../../Xml/bin/UMSM.009.8Root.xml". You could read the path from the app.config-file to be a little more flexible.

Comment: hate to ask so many questions, but how would I go about reading from my app.config-file?

Comment: reader Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation.  is the variable data I get for 'reader' when trying to perform ".../.../Xml/bin/UMSM.009.8Root.xml" for that line in debug

Comment: Only two dots!!! As an simple example add a key in your app.settings like: `<appSettings>    
    <add key="XmlFilesRelativePath" value="../../Xml/bin/"/></appSettings>` in c# code you could then do `string relativePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XmlFilesRelativePath"].ToString();` To create the XmlReader for a specific file call: `XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(relativePath + "UMSM.009.8Root.xml")`

Comment: ok, I'll try this. the <appSettings> tag just goes right into my Xml file correct?

Comment: No, it goes in the app.config file. Take a lock at this blogpost http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2006/01/04/64871.aspx There you can find a short introduction to use configuration in .NET2.0.

Comment: don't have 1 app.config file, i have 10 so this won't help

Comment: okay, this goes off topic. Do you have 10 of those because you need them, or did they appear "accidently"? The story of using the configuration file to store the path of your data-files was just an addon. The version with relative navigation (with two dots `"../../Xml/bin/UMSM.009.8Root.xml"`) works fine on my test project, so give it a try. the config solution is just another way to generate the same string.

Comment: unfortunately it just will not work for me, updated question^

Comment: i have no way of knowing an email, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Best to use XPathNavigator and XPath queries in .NET 2.0.
Reading attributes (like DisplayName in your example) is done by using @ in your XPath query.

There's a decent example [here](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/630817-how-get-attributes-xml-element-using-xpath). Although the XPathExpression bit isn't necessary, you could just call nav.Evaluate and provide the string XPath query directly.

Example XML (I needed to strip your namespace attributes):

```
<MonitorScope>
<PersonalSafety>    
    <MonitorResponseRecord Enabled="false" DisplayName="ValveFailureAtCentralPosition">
        <ExpressionMonitor>
            <postAlarm>
                <AlarmName>Valve_Position_Fault</AlarmName>
                <Parameter1> Sensor Position = {X}</Parameter1>
                <Parameter2> Sensor Position = {X}</Parameter2>
                <Parameter3> Sensor Position = {X}</Parameter3>
            </postAlarm>
        </ExpressionMonitor>
    </MonitorResponseRecord>
</PersonalSafety>
```

Code example using XPath:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml);

        XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
        XPathNodeIterator nodeList = nav.Select("//MonitorScope/PersonalSafety/MonitorResponseRecord");

        if (nodeList.Count != 0) {
            foreach (XPathNavigator node in nodeList) {
                // node queries are relative to MonitorResponseRecord node
                string displayName = node.SelectSingleNode("./@DisplayName").Value;

                string alarmName = node.SelectSingleNode("ExpressionMonitor/postAlarm/AlarmName").Value;
                string param1 = node.SelectSingleNode("ExpressionMonitor/postAlarm/Parameter1").Value;
                string param2 = node.SelectSingleNode("ExpressionMonitor/postAlarm/Parameter2").Value;
                string param3 = node.SelectSingleNode("ExpressionMonitor/postAlarm/Parameter3").Value;

                // do something with values
            }
        }
```